# Is there a way to test a css-selector query to an unappended element?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

I have this code:

```
Element.prototype.queryTest = function(strQuery) {
 var _r;
 if (this.parentElement == null) {
  _r = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(strQuery)).indexOf(this);
 } else {
  _r = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(strQuery)).indexOf(this);
 }
 return !!(_r+1);
}
```

I am searching for some way to test a query to an unappended element.

I want to change the first code to make this work:

```
var t = document.createElement("span");
t.classList.add("asdfg");
console.log(t.queryTest("span.adsfg"));
```

If there is a way to detect if the element isn't appended I could create a new temporary unappended one and append the target one to the temporary one to test the css-selector query.
Is there a way to detect if the element hasn't been appended jet? Could the target element be accessible even after freeing the temporary parent one? I have tested it on Chrome and it is accessible but I don't know if that is the case for firefox.

I know I can use document.querySelectorAll("*") to get a list of nodes but... isn't too CPU-demmanding the process to turn this NodeList to an Array? This is why I prefer not to use that way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a native [`Element.prototype.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method which does that:

```js
const el = document.createElement('span');
el.classList.add('test');
console.log(el.matches('span.test'));
```

Note that to check if a node is connected or not, there is the [`Node.prototype.isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) getter.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

```
Element.prototype.querySelectorTest = function(strQuery) {
 var _r;
 if (this.parentElement != null) {
  _r = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(strQuery),this);
 } else if (this == document.documentElement) {
  _r = ((document.querySelector(strQuery) == this)-1);
 } else {
  _r = ((this == document.createElement("i").appendChild(this).parentElement.querySelector(strQuery))-1);
 }
 return !!(_r+1);
}
```

I changed the way it check the nodeList.
I renamed the function to a more proper name.

If the target element is the root one there's no need to make a querySelectorAll.
If you append the unappended element to a temporary one to test the child you don't loose the reference (variable value in case there is one).

---

This is not my native language so please consider that.